# API Gateway Design Pattern - Backends for Frontends

Tags: design-patterns, api-design

I am contemplating the use of the design pattern API Gateway, specifically the Backends for Frontends derivative.

We have a number of 3rd party software packages that expose an API. Over the course of the past few years I have been creating custom APIs as wrappers for the functionality of these 3rd party APIs. These function in ways that make sense to our business processes.

As the number of applications (web and other) grow, it seems more like it would fit the API Gateway pattern so that we can loosely couple the custom APIs to the apps that use them. As well as tailor our API Gateway to function as a Facade for the client applications. We also need to start communications between the 3rd party software applications (integrate them with each other), as they don't currently offer any built in support.

We have mostly web applications, but we have also added a mobile application. The future could bring more mobile apps, but we will certainly be creating more web apps along the way. Some of these will be internal, some may be for clients outside our network, and some may be for external use, hence I got the idea for the API Gateway - Backends for Frontends idea.

Design References:

[backends-for-frontends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/backends-for-frontends)

[patterns-apigateway](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html)

As I have never designed something like this before, I was wondering the following:

1. **Have you experienced any other negative consequences from using this pattern other than these:**

Source: microservices.io - [patterns-apigateway](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html)

> The API gateway pattern has some drawbacks:
>
> Increased complexity - the API gateway is yet another moving part that
> must be developed, deployed and managed

> Increased response time due to
> the additional network hop through the API gateway - however, for most
> applications the cost of an extra roundtrip is insignificant.

<del>2. **As I am using the MVC pattern for the API Gateway, would you use a separate controller for each custom API it represents? Can you provide some guidance on structuring the controller(s) and routing recommendations?**</del>

3. **The documentation I have read, recommends using a single endpoint, which seems odd, as I wouldn't think you'd want to route everything through the same endpoint (method), ChatGPT told me differently and that using multiple controller(s) with multiple endpoints makes sense, perhaps I am misconstruing what they mean by a single endpoint (do they mean the base url?).**

Reference - Microsoft - [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/design/gateway)

> Use the gateway as a reverse proxy to route requests to one or more
> backend services, using layer 7 routing. The gateway provides a single
> endpoint for clients, and helps to decouple clients from services.

Comment: @Community Unhelpful. The question is specific in it's context and question(s)

Comment: @RyanWilson to say it a little more clearly, our Q&A format needs questions that have a single objective answer so that the votes mean something. Questions asking for an open ended list of things don’t work well here. We don’t do opinion polls.

Comment: @candied_orange question(s) 1 & 3 are pretty concrete imo. I can remove #2 if that's going to cause such an opinionated response. This is very unhelpful that Stack doesn't supply us with some place to ask discussion questions. As I specified in my post, I have no experience with this design pattern, I have no one at my job to get feedback from, and so it is up to me to make this design decision. I am trying to make the best possible decision and it would be helpful to get some feedback from experienced developers. What do you suggest, if not posting here?

Comment: We used to send people to Reddit but it’s a dumpster fire right now.

Comment: Consider looking at existing options for API gateways before building your own;  it's unclear what else the API gateway is needed for aside from forwarding requests, but if that's all you need then the 'getting started' tutorials for any popular API gateway should get you up and running in minutes.

Comment: @candied_orange That is unfortunate. I suppose I'll just have to go without any useful direction

Comment: @BenCottrell Thank you for engaging. The issue isn't how to build it so much as whether there are other downsides to this design pattern besides the two i listed from the second resource I linked and clarification on the "single" endpoint described in the summary

Comment: @RyanWilson The real issue is that the impact and consequences are project specific and implementation-dependent;  you will surely find people who had no issues with an API gateway in *their* project.  For each of those,  an equal number who found their implementation to be a relentless source of devops headaches which heavily impacted their project and their team's velocity.   The devil is in the detail, with the only way of measuring the real impact being just to try a proof-of-concept and test it as best as you can in a production-like environment.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand the 'endpoint' question in the context of an API gateway; it sounds like some small internal detail for the gateway itself, so therefore irrelevant when using one of the readily available API gateway options. All you should need is a configuration entry for the gateway which maps some externally facing route to the internal IP/Port of your real service.

Comment: Question #3 is not necessarily that opinion-based, but you need to cite your sources on that single endpoint thing @RyanWilson ... Who are "they" and what are they saying exactly?

Comment: @BenCottrell Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Where exactly? No matches for the word "endpoint" in either of them.

Comment: @guillaume31 My bad. I thought I had the link to Microsoft that contained that statement linked as the first link. Added it as a block quote and the reference to the article after #3. Please see edit

Comment: I think they mean "endpoint" in a general sense, not "API endpoint". A single server/service if you will, not a single resource/URI.

Comment: @guillaume31 Thank you. I appreciate your time. Ill be happy to upvote an answer and mark as accepted